# security exception error in  asp.net when using crystal report

Tags: asp.net, security, exception, crystal-reports, report

i have a website that contain a page that use crystal report to show some data.
its working fine on my computer , but when i uploaded on server it shows this error :

**Security Exception**

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\f02eda54\dd99b317\App_Web_jxjkj_he.1.cs    Line: 0

Answer (score 1):

I think the cause and the resolution of your problem are described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320268, check it out.